# React Weird thing happened to this.setState when working with some browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, and this issue I'm having is really upsetting. I am dynamically getting the key to set value for like so:

```
hangleChange: function (event) {
var target = event.currentTarget,
    target_id = target.id.toString(),
    target_value = target.value;

this.setState({ [target_id]: target_value }); // Syntax Error: "Unexpected token ["
}
```

This is throwing syntax errors on both IE and Chrome on Windows 7. Then I changed to

```
hangleChange: function (event) {
  var target = event.currentTarget,
      target_id = target.id.toString(),
      target_value = target.value;

  this.setState({ target_id: target_value }); // Removed "[]" that causes syntax error
}
```

It is not throwing error anymore, but it creates a new attribute `this.state.target_id` and sets that value to `target.value`. However, if I specify the specific `target_id` like `name` and set that value to `foobar` like this:

```
setState({ 'name': 'foobar' }) // works this way
```

it does the trick. But I just hope I could do this automatically so that I don't have to set a `handleChange` function for each and every changeable field in my app.

Have any of you had similar issues before? Any suggestions are welcomed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [computed property name syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```
{ [target_id]: target_value }
```

It was added to the language in ES2015 and won't work in particularly old browsers, including all versions of IE.

If you want to support older browsers, you'll need to do this instead:

```
var newState = {};
newState[target_id] = target_value;
this.setState(newState);
```

Many React developers use ES2015 (and beyond) features through the use of transpilers such as [Babel](http://babeljs.io) and a build tool like Webpack or Browserify. Googling something like "React Webpack ES6 tutorial" will bring up some good information, like this tutorial: http://jmfurlott.com/tutorial-setting-up-a-single-page-react-web-app-with-react-router-and-webpack/ It takes a certain amount of work to get set up, though.

Comment: Thank you, your answer and @alexander's answer below both do the trick. I wonder which is more preferred by people with more experiences in React?

Comment: My answer and his are identical except for the name of the variable, which is pretty arbitrary.

Comment: I'm gonna choose yours as the best answer since it is more complete, thanks!

Comment: this.setState({ [target_id]: target_value }); What is the es6 syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
hangleChange: function (event) {
  var target = event.currentTarget,
      target_id = target.id.toString(),
      target_value = target.value,
      state = {};

  state[target_id] = target_value;
  this.setState(state);
}
```